# Need to update a Unix Timestamp field with a date from Wordpress post_datetime in SQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

we have a field in table wp_postmeta with a Unix Timestamp date, but some with `NULL` instead the long number.

I need to find and replace all this Null dates with the same date-time from the post, directly in SQL.

I'm using `JOIN` to correctly select these posts, and works fine.

```
SELECT wp_posts . * 
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
WHERE 1 =1
AND wp_posts.post_type =  'my_post_type'
AND wp_postmeta.meta_value IS NULL 
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key =  'my_unix-date-timestamp_field'
```

I found this SQL command to "convert" the `post_datetime` to unix timestamp, but can't test:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(yourField);
```

BUT how can I use `UPDATE` and conversion in the same command?

I'm trying Updating but stuck

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET wp_postmeta.meta_value = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(post_datetime)
```

Could I collect the `post_datetime` in a select inside the `SET` command?